# iOS - Adding delay to a for loop

Tags: ios, swift, concurrency, queue, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to execute a series of tasks with a delay. To experiment that, I created a simple app with two labels and a button to perform hit test.

[image]

Upon hitting the "Hit me" button, yellow label must update the count instantly, where the red label must update the same count with a delay of 3 seconds. Below is my code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var hitMeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var actualCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var processedCountLabel: UILabel!
    
    private let delay: UInt32 = 3
    
    private var queuedHits: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            for hit in self.queuedHits {
                // First item to be updated instantly as the queue might be applied only to the items behind
                self.processedHits.append(hit)
                // Applying delay to the iteration for the rest of items
                sleep(self.delay)
            }
            self.queuedHits.removeAll()
        }
    }
    
    private var actualHits: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.actualCountLabel.text = "\(self.actualHits.count)"
            if let last = self.actualHits.last {
                self.queuedHits.append(last)
            }
        }
    }
    
    private var processedHits: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            self.processedCountLabel.text = "\(self.processedHits.count)"
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupInitialValues()
    }
    
    private func setupInitialValues() {
        actualCountLabel.text = "0"
        processedCountLabel.text = "0"
    }

    @IBAction func didHitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        actualHits.append(1)
    }
}
```

Here I use `sleep()` function to delay the execution. When I perform the hit test, I see that the entire app is frozen and both the labels update their count after 3 seconds. `sleep()` function does not satisfy my need here. What would be the proper way to do it?

My need is to iterate through the `queuedHits` with a delay and without blocking the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the DispatchQueue "asyncAfter" class to schedule the updates with a delay

private let delay: TimeInterval = 3

```
  for (index, hit) in self.queuedHits.enumerated() {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (delay * Double(index))) {
                    self.processedHits.append(hit)
                }
            }
```

Using "sleep" in the main thread can block the UI and make your app Hang

Comment: Your diagnosis that `sleep` is problematic is 100% right. But I'd suggest being careful with the scheduling of multiple `asyncAfter`, as you’ll be susceptible to timer coalescing (where some of the more distant tasks, if they're within 10% of each other, will be fire at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid traditional `sleep` calls, as those block the calling thread. While you could consider `asyncAfter`, that can run into timer coalescing problems.

The legacy solution would be to abandon a `for` loop and instead use a `Timer` where we remove one queued hit for each firing of the timer. And if a new hit needs to be queued while this timer is running, then no further action is required, as the timer will pick it up. E.g.:

```swift
private weak var timer: Timer?
private let delay: TimeInterval = 3

private var queuedHits: [Int] = [] {
    didSet {
        startTimerIfNecessary()
    }
}

func startTimerIfNecessary() {
    guard timer == nil else { return }

    timer = .scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: delay, repeats: true) { [weak self] timer in
        guard let self else {
            timer.invalidate()
            return
        }

        if queuedHits.isEmpty {
            timer.invalidate()
        } else {
            let hit = queuedHits.removeFirst()
            processedHits.append(hit)
        }
    }
    timer?.fire()
}
```

---

It, admittedly, can sometimes be hard to reason about asynchronous processes, so we often reach for `async`-`await`. Specifically, we might use for [`AsyncChannel`](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms/blob/main/Sources/AsyncAlgorithms/AsyncAlgorithms.docc/Guides/Channel.md) of Apple’s [Swift Async Algorithms](https://github.com/apple/swift-async-algorithms).

So we set up a routine to monitor the channel for new values and then [`Task.sleep`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/task/sleep(for:tolerance:clock:)) (which, unlike legacy `sleep` functions, does *not* block the thread):

```swift
private let delay: TimeInterval = 3
private let channel = AsyncChannel<Int>()

func monitorChannel() async throws {
    for await hit in channel {
        processedHits.append(hit)
        try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(delay))
    }
}
```

And when the view appears, we would start monitoring the channel, and when it disappears, cancel that task:

```swift
private var task: Task<Void, Error>?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    task = Task { try await monitorChannel() }
}

override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    task?.cancel()
}
```

---

So, pulling that together:

```swift
import AsyncAlgorithms

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var hitMeButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var actualCountLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var processedCountLabel: UILabel!

    private var actualHits: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            actualCountLabel.text = "\(actualHits.count)"
        }
    }

    private var processedHits: [Int] = [] {
        didSet {
            processedCountLabel.text = "\(processedHits.count)"
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupInitialValues()
    }


    private let delay: TimeInterval = 3
    private var task: Task<Void, Error>?
    private let channel = AsyncChannel<Int>()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        task = Task { try await monitorChannel() }
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
        task?.cancel()
    }
}

private extension ViewController {
    @IBAction func didHitButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        Task {
            actualHits.append(1)
            await channel.send(1)
        }
    }

    func setupInitialValues() {
        actualCountLabel.text = "0"
        processedCountLabel.text = "0"
    }

    func monitorChannel() async throws {
        for await hit in channel {
            processedHits.append(hit)
            try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(delay))
        }
    }
}
```